# Correct way to write a file in python (calling write function multiple times, or calling it once on a large string)

Tags: python

I am assuming just calling the write() function once is probably more performant and less redundant. But the real question is: "Does it really matter?"

This:

```
    file.write('hard coded text line 1\n');
    file.write('hard coded text line 2\n');
    file.write('hard coded text with variables line 3\n');
```

Or This:

```
        string = """
            hard coded text line1 \n
            hard coded text line2 \n
            .....
        """;

        file.write(string)
```

Comment: It depends. What is the context here? If you already have a full string, then just from the perspective of clarity/clean code, I would say write it all. As for performance, I would hesitate to pre-emptively optimize here, but again, this is really context dependant.

Answer (score 0):

Its just personal taste, but make sure they are equivalent. Remember that python's triple quoted strings include newlines and whitespace.

```
    string = """\
hard coded text line1
hard coded text line2
....."""
```

There is arguably a minor performance difference from calling `write` fewer times but that is lost in the noise of I/O.